# JCalendar: how to change the foreground color of certain days?

Tags: java, calendar, customization

i'm using the [JCalendar v 1.3.3](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html) component and i want to change the foreground color of certain days, by default the present days has red foreground, i want to emphatize other days with other colors. It's posible to archieve this with the present API or i have to modify the source code?

Comment: Which JCalendar? There seem to be a number of different implementations, none of them in the JDK. Please tell us the Web site you got it from, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll have to customise the JDayChooser component to make this happen as by default you you can only change the foreground colour of Sundays or Weekdays.

It shouldn't be too hard, take a look at the method `drawDayNames()` in the `JDayChooser` class.